# Selecting Data directly vs using navigation property in EF

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Hi there in a MVC application I have the following sample POCO classes(Actual application has 10-15 screens for employee data). Manager has many employees and he can update their personal and contact details. I am considering 3 approaches to retrieve the current employee data from database using EF.
1) When manager select an employee, store EmployeeId in Session (Session["currentEmp"]) and use this EmployeeId to get the data for the current employee.

like:

```
int employeeId = (int)Session["currentEmp"];
EmployeeContactDetails1 empCtDet1 = ctx.EmployeeContactDetails1.Find(employeeId);
then 
EmployeeContactDetails2 empCtDet2 = ctx.EmployeeContactDetails2.Find(employeeId);
```

2) Have a discriminator property such as "unlocked" on Employee class and when manager select the employee then mark it unlocked = true and update the column in database and the do something like this for further data retrieval

```
EmployeeContactDetails1 empCtDet1 = ctx.Employees.Where(e => e.unlocked == true).EmployeeContactDetails1;
EmployeeContactDetails2 empCtDet2 = ctx.Employees.Where(e => e.unlocked == true).EmployeeContactDetails2;
```

3) Or

```
EmployeeContactDetails1 empCtDet1 = ctx.EmployeeContactDetails1.Where(e => e.Employee.unlocked == true).FirstOrDefault();
    EmployeeContactDetails2 empCtDet2 = ctx.EmployeeContactDetails2.Where(e => e.Employee.unlocked == true).FirstOrDefault();
```

I would like to ask you which one is better keeping in mind security and performance.

```
public class Manager{
public int ManagerId{get;set;}
public string ManagerName{get;set;}
public string someMoreProp{get;set;}
public ICollection<Employee>Employee{get;set;}
}

public class Employee{
public int EmployeeId{get;set;}
public virtual EmployeePersonalDetails EmployeePersonalDetails{get;set;}
public virtual EmployeeContactDetails EmployeeContactDetails{get;set;}

public int ManagerId{get;set;}
public virtual Manager Manager{get;set;}
}


   public class EmployeePersonalDetails{
    public int EmployeeId{get;set;}
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public string Age{get;set;}
    public Address AddressOne{get;set;}
    public Employee Employee{get;set;}
    }

    public class EmployeeContactDetails1{
    public int EmployeeId{get;set;}
    public string Line1{get;set;}
    public string Line2{get;set;}
public Employee Employee{get;set;}
    }

    public class EmployeeContactDetails2{
    public int EmployeeId{get;set;}
    public string Line1{get;set;}
    public string Line2{get;set;}
public Employee Employee{get;set;}
    }
    public class EmployeeContactDetails3{
    public int EmployeeId{get;set;}
    public string Line1{get;set;}
    public string Line2{get;set;}
public Employee Employee{get;set;}
    }

    public class EmployeeContactDetails4{
    public int EmployeeId{get;set;}
    public string Line1{get;set;}
    public string Line2{get;set;}
    public Employee Employee{get;set;}
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, don't use `Session`. The mentioned way you're considering is a completely unacceptable use of sessions. A well-designed web app will as much as feasibly possible avoid sessions like the plague. The notable exception is of course authentication, which can't be achieved in a user-friendly way by any other means.

Second, in general, you seem to be making this far too complicated. It's not entirely clear what you're trying to achieve, but it sounds like you simply want the manager to be able to do something like click on an employee and then be taken to a view where they can edit that employee's details. The correct way to do that is to have a dedicated URI, consisting of the employee id or some other uniquely identifying token. For example:

```
/employees/{id}/edit
```

Then, in the action that that URI routes to, you would use the id param to look up the employee:

```
var employee = db.Employees.Find(id);
if (employee == null)
{
    return new HttpNotFoundResult();
}
```

Since, presumably, you would only want the manager of that employee to be able to edit the employee, you would simply do object-level authorization by including the manager's id in the query:

```
var managerId = User.Identity.GetUserId(); // currently logged in manager
var employee = db.Employees.SingleOrDefault(m => m.EmployeeId == id && m.ManagerId == managerId);
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. The thing is I do not want to expose the employee's ID. Do you think supplying employee's ID would be safe in a finance related application?

Comment: and if I go with your solution on the next screen I'll have to do this: var managerId = User.Identity.GetUserId(); // currently logged in manager
var empPrsnlDetail = db.EmployeePersonalDetails.SingleOrDefault(m => m.EmployeeId == id && **m.Employee.ManagerId == managerId**);

Comment: in this case can't I do something like this rather than passing EmployeeId in URI?: var managerId = User.Identity.GetUserId(); // currently logged in manager
var empPrsnlDetail = db.EmployeePersonalDetails.SingleOrDefault(m => **m.Employee.Unlocked == true** && **m.Employee.ManagerId == managerId**);

Comment: You can also give away all your money and live in a cardboard box on the side of the highway. You can do a lot of things. Whether you *should* is a different story, and here, no you should not do it that way. URLs are supposed to be unique identifiers for a particular resource. This kind of thing violates the entire core principles of HTTP and is brittle and error prone, to boot.

Comment: Thanks again. Could you please advise me what is the best way to get the data for next view? I mean data from EmployeePersonalDetails table since that is related to Employee table having EmployeeId as pk? I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: var managerId = User.Identity.GetUserId(); // currently logged in manager var empPrsnlDetail = db.EmployeePersonalDetails.SingleOrDefault(ed => ed.EmployeeId == id && ed.Employee.ManagerId == managerId); Would you recommend this?

Comment: Actually, I would just do: `db.Employees.Include(m => m.EmployeePersonalDetails).SingleOrDefault(...)`. That will eagerly load the related record and you can just reference it off the employee, i.e. `employee.EmployeePersonalDetails`.

Comment: The thing is I do not need whole employee data In EmployeePersonalDetails View, Using "include" returns too much data which I do not need. Thats why I was thinking about using db.EmployeePersonalDetails.SingleOrDefault(ed => ed.EmployeeId == id && ed.Employee.ManagerId == managerId); What is your view on this?

Comment: Well, that would let you use `Select` to pick only a certain subset of fields, but right now you aren't doing that, so using the code you're talking about would be no different than using `Include`, at this point.

Comment: However, bear in mind that Entity Framework works with *objects*, not datasets. That is to say that if you intend to update that record, you'll need the *full object with all it's data*. Otherwise, EF will take you to mean that you want any data not present to be set to NULL, which is obviously not right. If you want to work with partial entity data, then you'll need to use something like Dapper, rather than EF, so you can write your own select and update statements.

Comment: I read your answer on using identity claims somewhere. What is your view on saving EmployeeId in user claim and then get empId from user claim and use it like: var empPrsnDtail = ctx.EmployeePersonalDetails.SingleOrDefault(e =>e.EmployeeId== empId)

Comment: That would be 100% the wrong way to do things. What is the issue with having the id in the URL *as it should be*?

Comment: Using id in URL results in very complex query like: var mgrId = User.Identity.GetUserId(); then you do ctx.Employee.SingleOrDefault(e => e.Id && e.MgrId == mgrId)// upto here everything is fine. After this if I do this as you advised ctx.Employee.Include(d => d.EmpPrsnDtl).SingleOrDefault(e => e.Id && e.MgrId == mgrId) This return data from Employee table as well as data from EmpPrsnDtl table while I need data only from EmpPrsnDtl for EmpPrsnDtl view and EmpPrsnDtl has further navigation property like AddressOne which would further complicate the things.

Comment: and the following query which you previously advised me is a wrong way to go about result in too many joins: ctx.AddressOne.SingleOrDefault(a => a.EmpPrsnDtl.Employee.MgrId == mgrId && a.AddressOneId == id)

Comment: If you need only `EmpPrsnDtl` then query that instead, but you're still going to have joins. There's no way around that because it has to check the relationships on the other tables.

Comment: Chris can you spare few minutes please I really need your help about it. May be in a chat?

Comment: If I query EmpPrsnDtl then I am coming back to same square I started from. Because my query will be like this ctx.AddressOne.SingleOrDefault(a =>a.EmpPrsnDtl.Employee.IsCurrent == true && a.EmpPrsnDtl.Employee.MgrId == mgrId && a.AddressOneId == id)

Comment: Not sure if it's going to let you talk or not as your rep is too low. I tried to give you explicit write access, which should skirt around the rep threshold, but it appears to be broken. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123253/selecting-data-directly-vs-using-navigation-property-in-ef

Comment: I have another account If we can use that?

Comment: If you have another account with higher rep, why are you using a new one?

Comment: Hi @ChrisPratt its me Harvey